# URL name in django template.if statement

Tags: django, django-templates

How to add correctly in my example `{% url 'myview' %}`

```
{% if request.path == {% url 'myview' %} %}
```

?

Answer (score 17):

Django has this nice [built-in feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) that you can assign the url to a variable and then use it:

```
{% url 'myview' as my_view %}
{% if request.path == my_view %}
```